# I want to solve the implicit equation y = (5.172*(10+4.472*y)^0.4)/(10+2*y) using python

Tags: python, sympy, equation

This actually concerns with solving the discharge equation
Q= 1/n*A*R^(2/3)*S^(1/2)

where in instead of depth 'y' discharge 'Q' will be known and the depth would be found out by taking an initial approximation in the conventional way.

What I want is to develop a code in python that would solve for depth 'y' iteratively when given an initial approximation.

Comment: Q = 1/n * A * R ^(2/3) * S^(1/2)

Comment: Python is not particularly great in cpu intense operations like this. Instead you could use Wolfram Alpha's API to build a python calculator that uses their API

Answer (score 1):

SymPy can easily solve this with the `nsolve` function:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import y
>>> eq = y - (5.172*(10+4.472*y)**0.4)/(10+2*y)
>>> from sympy import nsolve
>>> nsolve(eq, 1)
1.24179016236282
```

Answer (score 1):

Python isn't great for CPU intensive operations like this. Approximating with pure Python with iterative method probably won't work. If the solution is guaranteed to be integer and you know the upper, lower bound of it, then you can use binary search. but for real number approximation it's pointless to do it with pure python.

Fortunately there are some libraries for this.

Here's a one-liner example:

```
import scipy.optimize as opt
sol=opt.fsolve(lambda y:(5.172*(10+4.472*y)**0.4)/(10+2*y)-y , 0)
print(sol)

# prints [1.24179016]
# this solves the equation of (function =0)
# note that the second argument '0' doesn't mean the target value
# target value is always 0. so you need to make a (equation)=0 form
# 2nd argument means initial estimated value,
# so it doesn't matter whether you put 0 or 1 or 100 there.
# you can give a function that returns multiple equations as the first
# argument to solve multi variable equations
```

You have to install scipy library. (using pip)