# Limit NaN comparison

Tags: python

I am a beginner, this is The question:

[image: The question]

I have tried:

```
Listttt=[0]
for n in range(9999):
    
    XN=(sin(n)**2)/n 
    
    if XN >= 1.e-9:
        Listttt.append(XN)

KK=len(Listttt)-1
print(KK)
```

But it says "Invalid NaN comparison"

Comment: No idea for the NaN, you should get a ZeroDivisionError first on the first iteration with n=0.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out:D

Comment: You can solve the equation using scipy.optimizer.fsolver and apply int function on the 0th element of returned list to get the answer. Don't need to create Listtt for that. check out my answer on another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69866425/i-want-to-solve-the-implicit-equation-y-5-172104-472y0-4-102y-usin/69866741#69866741

Comment: Not sure for the NaN, it is probably linked to your division by zero error pointed out above. One small remark though: you might want to consider using a `while` loop instead of a very long `for` loop, or better yet, an infinte `for` loop using the `itertools.count()` iterator. That would help you in case the size of the list you are looking for is actually bigger than 9999.

Comment: @jeffpentagon he’s explicitely asked to create the list, and using scipy.optimizer seems very overkill for that problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Mathieu in the comments, the error is due to the fact you are beginning at 0 instead of 1:

How do you find that error? First it is telling you there is a NaN comparison. There is only one comparison in your code: `XN >= 1.e-9`

1e-9 is not NaN, so `XN` must be. Therefore the error lies on the line `XN=(sin(n)**2)/n`. There are few ways to get a `NaN` result, and almost all of them are invalid operations. `0/0` or `inf - inf` for example.

I suspect you are using `numpy.sin` and not `math.sin`. Hence you are working with numpy floats instead of regular python floats. The difference is that on division by 0, python floats raise an error, while **by default numpy fails silently and sets the number to `NaN`**.

and to prove it, you can test it:

```py
In : np.sin(0) ** 2 / 0
out : nan
```

Since you are a beginner, I will tell you other remarks I have on your code:

1. You’re asked for the list length, but you are returng `len(Listtt) - 1`, that may be an error
2. Using a `for n in range(9999)` here is a suboptimal: it will fail if you need more than 9999 elements. You should use a `while` loop or an infinite `for` loop like `for n in itertools.count()` (and since you need to start at 1, it should be `for n in itertools.count(1)`.
3. `Listtt` is a pretty bad variable name (especially if you also have `List` and `Listt`, it is going to make your code very confusing to read), you could call it something more explicit like `xn_list`.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted